# how to create a window of a given size?

Tags: python, tkinter

please help fix the code

```
import tkinter

def makeWorkArea(parent):
    WorkArea = tkinter.Frame(parent)
    WorkArea.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
    WorkArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

    msg = tkinter.Label(WorkArea, text='Window menu basics')
    msg.pack()

root = tkinter.Tk()
makeWorkArea(root)
root.mainloop()
```

the problem is that the parameters are specific dimensions packer area WorkArea, but after starting the program for some reason, a window smaller (approximately equal to the size lettering msg). whether it is possible to do so after the launch created a window of 340x170 pixels, bathed in red. and placed in the window text msg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `grid` and `pack` geometry managers do what is called "geometry propagation". That's a fancy name for saying that frames and windows shrink or expand to fit their contents. This is almost always exactly what you want.

If you want to make a frame a specific size, the best solution is to turn geometry propagation off. When you do that, the widget will honor the `width` and `height` attributes and ignore the size of any child widgets.

See the last line in the following code:

```
def makeWorkArea(parent):
    WorkArea = tkinter.Frame(parent)
    WorkArea.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
    WorkArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

    WorkArea.pack_propagate(False)
```

Note that turning propagation off is often a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It usually means you're doing something wrong. Tkinter is very good at making widgets just the right size. By turning this off, you are completely responsible for making widgets the appropriate size, which can be difficult in the face of different screen resolutions, different fonts, and when the user resizes the window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want the [`tkinter.Tk.geometry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) method:

```
import tkinter

def makeWorkArea(parent):
    WorkArea = tkinter.Frame(parent)
    WorkArea.config(relief = 'sunken', width = 340, height = 170, bg = 'red')
    WorkArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

    msg = tkinter.Label(WorkArea, text='Window menu basics')
    msg.pack()

root = tkinter.Tk()
###########################
root.geometry("340x170")
###########################
makeWorkArea(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The line in the comment box sets the window's initial size to `340x170` pixels.

Comment: That this will fix the size of the whole window, not the size of the inner frame. If your whole window is composed only of the inner frame, you might get the desired effect with some window managers. It's up to the window manager to decide if the dimensions include or exclude the window border -- that is, if you want the _inside_ to be a specific size, `geometry` may actually set the _outside_ depending on what window manager you use.